# flatten SQL columns based on modification timestamp

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have (to access) a table with dozens of columns.
The rows contain deltas compared to latest version.
Each row represents a person that made the changes.

e.g.

```
id    item col_a col_b col_c (many more columns) modified_by  modified_on
123   1    A     one   red                                 1  2017-12-01 10:00
721   1          three                                     4  2020-03-12 10:00
974   1    B     two                                       5  2019-10-06 10:00
```

Would like to receive:

```
      item col_a col_b col_c (many more columns) modified_on
      1    B     three red                       2020-03-12 10:00
```

And optional: `created_on: 2017-12-01 10:00` and `last_updated_by: 4`.

Note: the rows are not necessarily in order (row 721 was e.g. created in 2018 and updated in 2020).
For each column the max modified_on should be used.

Want to avoid something like this

```
select item,
  <"max" of col_a>,
  <"max" of col_b>,
  ...
  <"max" of col_xyz>
from mytable
group by item
```

as the table has dozens of columns and it could be the table columns change over time, which makes it tricky to maintain.

DB is sqlsrv, but plain SQL is preferred.

How can I efficiently flatten the DB?

Answer (score 0):

You seem want the most recent non-NULL value for each column.

One method uses `apply`:

```
select *
from (select distinct item from history) i outer apply
     (select top (1) h2.col_a
      from history h2
      where h2.item = i.item and h2.col_a is not null
      order by h2.modified_on
     ) a outer apply
     (select top (1) h2.col_b
      from history h2
      where h2.item = i.item and h2.col_b is not null
      order by h2.modified_on
     ) b outer apply
     . . .   -- repeat for each column
```

Note:  This is essentially implementing `last_value(ignore nulls)`, which is part of the SQL standard.  However, SQL Server does not support that functionality.

Another method -- which might be faster -- uses window functions:

```
select distinct h.item,
       max(col_a) over (partition by item, grp_a) as imputed_col_a,
       max(col_b) over (partition by item, grp_b) as imputed_col_b,
       . . .
from (select h.*,
             count(col_a) over (partition by item order by modified_on) as grp_a,
             count(col_b) over (partition by item order by modified_on) as grp_b,
             . . .
      from history
     ) h
```

Note:  If you want other columns, I would suggest you settle on a method and ask a new question.

Comment: The summary is correct (and nice and short): yes, the most recent non-NULL value. Thanks for the suggestion. Was hoping *not* to deal with each column individually. Will (have to) look for alternative approach where I get the raw data from DB and flatten afterwards (outside DB).